# project using RFID and module ESP-01 connect in android studio

Tags: java

je veut crée une application en Android studio qui jouent le rôle de recevoir tout les mouvement dans le partie électronique (RFID ,ARDUINO, ESP-01,buzer,led, lcd_I2C,et servomoteur) quand il y a une carte présente sur le RFID ,il y a une notification sur l'appk grâce a la module wifi ESP-01 , mais il y a aussi une bouton d'historique pour voir tous le carte qui passe (ex aujourd'hui) , le premier bouton et pour connecte a la réseaux wifi; aide moi

je veut une code en Android et en Arduino